# Sort Dynamics CRM Chart Series by Month and Then Year

Tags: reporting-services, charts, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a chart with a measure based on data 'since the start of last year'. It's easy to chart it like this:

```
  *                         *
  *                         *      *
  *      *                  *      *
  *      *      *           *      * 
Jan13  Feb13  Mar13 - - - Jan14  Feb14
```

How can I represent it like this, so that months from 13/14 can be compared side by side

```
  *      *                   
  *      *             *           
  *      *       *     *           
  *      *       *     *     *      
Jan13  Jan14  Feb13  Feb14 Mar13 - -
```

I have tried out of the box charting, setting the category by month and then year, but it complains that I can't reuse the group-by field more than once.

I think I could do this by editing the xml in one of two ways:

- Filter the set for 'this year' and 'last year' then offset the plot of one series so that they appear side by side
- Replicate what would be done in SSRS - category by month, series by year, sorted by month.

How can I edit the xml to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

How about achieving your desired result like this?

- Customizing the chart entity to add a property
- Updating this field via Workflow on chart entity's Date property update like

  - 0113 (xxJan13)
  - 0114 (xxJan14)
  - 0213 (xxFeb13)
  - 0214 (xxFeb14) and so on
- Using this property to group and order the chart data